# Generate a spending report from the following tables

Tags: mysql, django-models, django-queryset

My current project is to generate a spending report from the following tables. The complete report is to show a user's spending $ breakdown by Franchise's retail category, such as

User 1

retail_category 1: $20

retail_category 2: $30

retail_category 3: $35

User 2

retail_category 1: $10

retail_category 2: $15

retail_category 3: $5

Here are the tables:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id_user = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)

class Franchises(models.Model):
    id_franchise = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    retail_category = models.IntegerField(default=99)  # values are 1 to 13

class Stores(models.Model):
    id_store = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    franchise = models.ForeignKey(Franchises, db_column='id_franchise')

class Receipts(models.Model):
    id_receipt = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Stores, db_column='id_store')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='id_user')
    grand_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4)
```

I'd appreciate any raw mysql or django model query.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I'm translating your django schema spec to raw mysql correctly:

```
SELECT user, retail_category, SUM(grand_total)
FROM Receipts
INNER JOIN Stores ON Receipts.store = Stores.id_store
INNER JOIN Franchises ON Stores.franchise = Franchises.id_franchise
GROUP BY user, retail_category;
```

Comment: it works except you need inner join user on receipts.user id = user id. thanks